# Subprocess not working with complex Unix command

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I am trying to run a `join` command within Python, and I'm being foiled by `subprocess`.  I'm combining thousands of large files iteratively, so a dictionary would require a lot of memory.  My rationale is that `join` only has to deal with two files at a time, so my memory overhead will be lower.

I have tried many different versions of this trying to get `subprocess` to run.  Can anyone explain why this is not working?  When I print the `cmd` and execute it myself on the shell, it runs perfectly.

```
cmd = "join <(sort %s) <(sort %s)" % (outfile, filename) 
with open(out_temp, 'w') as out:
     return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=out, shell=True)
if return_code != 0:
     print "not working!"
     break
```

The error produced looks like this.  However, when I have python print `cmd` and execute it myself on the shell, it runs perfectly.

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I have also tried turning the command into a list, but I'm not sure what the rationale is for how to break up the commands.  Can anyone explain?  `outfile` and `filename` are variables

```
["join" , "<(sort" , outfile , ") <(sort" , filename , ")"]
```

Any help would be appreciated!  I'm doing this in Python because I'm heavily parsing filenames upstream to figure out which files to combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<(` is a `bash` extension to standard shell syntax. Notice in the error message that it's running `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`; even if `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`, `bash` drops many of its extensions when it's run using that link.

You can use `bash` explicitly with:

```
cmd = "bash -c 'join <(sort %s) <(sort %s)'" % (outfile, filename)
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Works perfectly now!